# Storing video and then playback from specific location

Tags: video, mpeg, mpeg-4

We are working on a project on which we need to store video while user perform different events on machine... we store the time stamp of each event performed by user and then want to playback video for specific events selected by user.

Can anyone help us in this regard that how we could achieve this? I mean do we need to store video in mpeg format? how could we play back video from specific location between video. We don't want to store videos in different chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Video playback can either happen using Flash - you need to have player like Flow Player and keep your content.

In modern days now the alternative is to use WebM. The video need to be On2.

For delivering playback basically you need the media server like Flash Media server, [Red5](http://www.red5.org/), [Live555](http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/) or similar. They all have support for different formats and protocol.